# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable WebElement object Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
posts = driver.find_elements(locate_with(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a").below(newFirstText).above(footer))
            while isPostFound == False:
                postURLs = {}
                for x in posts:
                    try:
                        y = x.get_attribute('href')
                        postURLs[x] = y
                    except:
                        pass
                for k,v in postURLs:
                    if k not in postsLiked:
                        driver.find_element(locate_with(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.eLAPa > div._9AhH0").below(v)).click()
                        isPostFound = True
                    else:
                        isPostFound = False
                        pass
```

Я нахожу все ссылки на сайте по тегу `а` и получению атрибута `href`. Я заношу в словарик:
`WebElement: Ссылка`. Проверяю ссылку на наличие в списке, а затем должен искать пост после `WebElement`, соответствующего ссылке. Однако, получаю ошибку:

> ```
> for k,v in postURLs: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable WebElement object"
> ```

Возможно ли распаковать `WebElement` из словарика?

Comment: `for k,v in postURLs.items():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в этой строке:

```
for k,v in postURLs:
```

Нельзя писать `for переменная(-ые) in словарь`. Это Вам не список.

Нужно сделать, как сказал **@GrAnd** в комментарии:

```
for k,v in postURLs.items():
```

Это если Вам нужно пройтись по *значениям* словаря.
Если же (не в этом случае) нужно пройтись по *ключам* словаря, сделайте так:

```
for k,v in postURLs.keys():
```